# TableLayoutPanel doesnt display my pictureBoxes

Tags: c#, user-interface, picturebox, tablelayoutpanel

I want to get all PowerPoint slides of my current presentation and add them with picture boxes to my table layout panel, but my picture boxes are not displayed for some reason.

```
public partial class PPT_GUI : Form
{
    public PPT_GUI(PowerPoint.Slides Sld)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int rowCount = 1;
        PictureBox[] Box;
        Box = new PictureBox[Sld.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < Sld.Count; i++)
        {
            Sld[i+1].Copy();
            Box[i] = new PictureBox();
            Box[i].Width = 90;
            Box[i].Height = 90;
            Box[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            Box[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            Box[i].BringToFront();

            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Box[i], i%3, rowCount );

            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 360F));
                rowCount++;
            }              

            if (Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
            {
                ImageSource imgSource = BinaryStructConverter.ImageFromClipboardDib();
                Box[i].Image = ImageWpfToGDI(imgSource);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Disregard my answer.  You are adding it, I just didn't see it before.